# How to let loading activity waits until thread finishs

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, android-activity

Hello i have an application that makes a session by making a file with user information and password encrypted ... the encryption operation takes some time i've added an activity which has a loading theme my question is how to join encryption thread from the loading activity while it's not in the same activity class like this

```
            //encryption thread Thread t1=....
          Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoadingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and here i want a code to join t1 while i'm in loading activity and t1 is in Login activity

```
          //after joining the thread   
   Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.class, LoginActivity.this);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Use a broadcast receiver in login activity

Comment: You could use `Thread.join`.

Comment: Learn a bit about ProgressDialog and AsyncTask. And rethink about your problem.

Comment: @Shaiful Thanks a lot. Can you write it as an answer so i can tick it , so people can see that it's answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProgressDialog` will let you show dialog while waiting for background task to complete. You can combine with `AsyncTask` to show /hide the dialog and also do the background works. Though `Thread` will also work.

You can use other means of progress indicator instead of `ProgressDialog`, activate or deactivate through `AsyncTask` method.